# Remote spark-submit not working via paramiko

Tags: python, apache-spark, spark-submit

My spark program is in remote ubuntu system. Now I want to execute it from windows system using paramiko(a python package for SSH2 connections).

[The program in windows for remote execution of spark program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aimzP.png)

The problem is that I can execute python program in remote ubuntu system, but can not execute the spark program.  Anyone knows why?

Comment: Are you able to ssh to that host with same user with you want launch spark app ?

Comment: Yes, I can ssh to the host from Windows and can execute general python program in the host, but can not execute spark program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you should set spark environmental variables. On remote instance where you want launch your spark application make an entry for spark in .bashrc file

```
SPARK_HOME=*<path to your spark folder>*

export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

then source the changed .bashrc file by the command

```
source  ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: It's really the path problem ! So I use the whole path like ‘/home/username/.../spark/bin/spark-submit xxx.py’, it worked ! But I can not  get the environment variable, so the path like '$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit xxx.py' could not work even though I set the environment variables correctly. Of course this is another problem. Thanks again!